# C# Precompile code save to user created Configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, precompile

I have a few different configurations for testing purposes and I used to use the debug and Release versions but we had to make it more granular with Alpha, Beta, RC and Release versions.  I used to use this code, which worked correctly:

```
#if Debug
    var TestVersion = true;
#else
    var TestVersion = false;
#endif
```

However, because I have more configurations now, this is what I have:

```
#if Alpha
            var Version = "Alpha";
#elif Beta
            var Version = "Beta";
#elif RC
            var Version = "RC";
#else 
            var Version = "Production";
#endif
```

How can I get the code to compile in to the correct configurations?  Every configuration is defaulting to the #else Production Version

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Configuration Manager and add New build configurations that matches your names (just for the sake of clarity).

[image]

Then for each configuration, switch to it and then go the the project settings and specify the `Conditional compilation symbol`

[image]

After that whenever you switch the configuration the corresponding code should be enabled.

[image]

Comment: Pawel, I already created Build Configurations that match those names and it isn't working.  That is the issue that I am having.

Comment: and did you define the 'Conditional compilation symbols` ? I've did all those steps before publishing. Works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were talking about something else.  I cannot find where to add them.

Comment: after adding the Conditional variable, you need to switch your project to use that configuration